# float: left breakage

Tags: jquery

Compare this http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/tbYsM/1/ which works with this http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/tbYsM/2/ which doesn't.

The first is just a block of text. The second, I've attempted to split it into two columns next to each other. I've surrounded the text with  tags including  which is the bit that breaks it.

Any ideas what the solution is?

JQUery

```
    var $block1 = $(".block1");
var $block2 = $(".block2");
var $blog_slide_container = $('#blog_slide_container');
$blog_slide_container.animate({height: $block1.outerHeight()});

$(function() {
$(".left_slide").click(function() {
    $block1.stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 500, function () { $(this).hide(); });
    $blog_slide_container.animate ({height: $block2.outerHeight()});
    $block2.stop(true, true).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);

});

$(".right_slide").click(function() {
    $block1.show();
    $blog_slide_container.animate({height: $block1.outerHeight()});
    $block2.stop(true, true).animate({ left: 400 }, 500);
    $block1.stop(true, true).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a div with a `clear: left;` after the two floated divs. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/ZahDf/) it is in action.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to put the `float: left;` on the outer div and then `clear: both;` or `clear: left;` on the inner one.  See the update: http://jsfiddle.net/tbYsM/4/